# What could happen, if we dont leave Beta

Tags: support

During promoting for more upvotes to be able leaving Beta I got asked if it would be bad, if we dont leave beta.

So now I ask, could there be a penalty, if we dont leave beta?

Answer (score 7):

A few reasons being 'stuck' would be bad:

**Moderators:**

In my opinion the longer we're stuck in beta the longer we're stuck with pro-tem moderators. Since the last moderator election the participation of the community has widened and we can see who now has the time and effort to invest in moderation. This means that they're also stuck with moderating until graduation. This isn't fair to them, and the burden at some point needs to be shouldered.

**SO questions won't be migrated**

As with ServerFault, Programmers, we would enjoy the benefit of being able to migrate all Magento-centric questions here. We get the odd ones from time to time - but having them all flow to this site would only increase its value to the community.

**Branding**

Less of an issue, but not having a properly designed SE-site theme makes us less legit and perhaps contributes to the high number of flyby questions; people just don't know/remember who we are and how to get back here.

**URL?**

The **.stackexchange.com** may stick around as it has recently with other beta launches - and maybe a mod can answer to this - but how cool would mageoverflow.com be?

Comment: +5 for mageoverflow.com

Comment: +10 for mageoverflow.com ;)

Comment: unless you have special powers only +1 (or multiple accounts) is possible ;-)

Comment: I have special powers, but I can only go up to +5. I guess @davidalger is twice as powerful as I am. :)

Answer (score 2):

StackExchange are pretty good at letting only "mature" sites make it to "the big league". I doubt that they will let the site go away. There's a lot of activity and visibility here, and I see that trend increasing (based on my time spent moderating)

I think that we may soon see some increased visibility for the Magento SE site which will hopefully help drive traffic, grow the community (which will need remediation for sure).

We just all need to knuckle up and buckle up to ensure that the good content bubbles up and that users get the help they need.

It would be nice to get a custom domain name, but this privilege is reserved for a select few sites on the SE network; ref http://stackexchange.com/sites.